# Change Twig Loader order

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony6

So I've created a few twig loaders in my project for templates stored in databases. Simply having them implement LoaderInterface already automatically adds them to the default Twig\Loader\ChainLoader - however, I haven't found a way to configure the order.

When I check which loaders are in the ChainLoader, it's

```
LoaderA -> LoaderB -> FilesystemLoader
```

, but I want the order to be

```
FilesystemLoader -> LoaderB -> LoaderA
```

If I define twig.loader in my services.yaml, it always ends up with infinite recursion and nothing works. If I manually configure the calls to twig.loader.chain, I get the correct order of loaders, followed by a chainloader X, followed by the loaders in the "autoconfigured" order. Chainloader X is the same as the very ChainLoader Symfony configures, so... infinite recursion if a template is not found.

So how on earth do I tell twig which loaders to load in what order? Do I need to create a CompilerPass just for this simple requirement?

Comment: @DarkBee this question is specific to Symfony, changing Loaders works different when using Twig as a standalone. Please leave Symfony in the title.

Comment: [There is no reason at all to add tags to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the order by [tagging the services manually](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#tagged-services-with-priority), when `priority` is not specified it defaults to `0`:

```
# services.yaml
    App\Twig\LoaderA:
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.loader', priority: 2 }
    App\Twig\LoaderB:
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.loader', priority: 1 }
```

If you prefer, since Symfony 5.3 (running under PHP 8), you can use [PHP attributes](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-service-autoconfiguration-and-attributes) instead.

Comment: Thank you, using negative values makes it possible to get the FilesystemLoader first :)

`#[Autoconfigure(tags: [['name' => 'twig.loader', 'priority' => -2]])]`